# What is the probability function of $\text{Beta}(1/2, 1/2)$ supposed to look like?

Tags: statistics

What is the probability function of $\text{Beta}(1/2, 1/2)$ supposed to look like?

Something like: (ignoring the constant part)

$\theta^{-0.5}(1-\theta)^{-0.5} $ or do we keep the exponents positive even though $0.5-1 = -0.5$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct. There's no reason to suddenly make the exponent positive. Here's a graph:

[image: Here's the image!]

Comment: This is also known as the [arcsine distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcsine_distribution).